# partition a set of images into k clusters with opencv

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, label, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have an image data set that I would like to partition into k clusters. I am trying to use the opencv implementation of k-means clustering.

Firstly, I store my Mat images into a vector of Mat and then I am trying to use the kmeans function. However, I am getting an assertion error. 
Should the images be stored into a different kind of structure? I have read the k-means documentation and I dont seem to understand what I am doing wrong. This is my code:

Thank you in advance,

```
vector <Mat> images;
string folder = "D:\\football\\positive_clustering\\";
string mask = "*.bmp";

vector<string> files = getFileList(folder + mask);

for (int i = 0; i < files.size(); i++)
{
    Mat img = imread(folder + files[i]);
    images.push_back(img);
}

cout << "Vector of positive samples created" << endl;



int k = 10;
cv::Mat bestLabels;
cv::kmeans(images, k, bestLabels, TermCriteria(), 3, KMEANS_PP_CENTERS);

//have a look
vector<cv::Mat> clusterViz(bestLabels.rows);
for (int i = 0; i<bestLabels.rows; i++)
{
    clusterViz[bestLabels.at<int>(i)].push_back(cv::Mat(images[bestLabels.at<int>(i)]));
}

namedWindow("clusters", WINDOW_NORMAL);
for (int i = 0; i<clusterViz.size(); i++)
{
    cv::imshow("clusters", clusterViz[i]);
    cv::waitKey();
}
```

Comment: [kmeans](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d5/d38/group__core__cluster.html#ga9a34dc06c6ec9460e90860f15bcd2f88) is used to partition *2D points* not images.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a way that I can use it to partition nxd dimensional images? Could you suggest an other method for grouping a set of images into k clusters?

Comment: kmeans is not limited to 2D points, it can cluster N-D points. So you can use kmeans to cluster the images, just treat the image as a vector(1xN) by converting matrix to 1xN.

Comment: Thank you. Should the values be stored in pixel-wise order ? for example (r,g,b,r,g,b, r,g,b....)

Comment: welcome. Yes, that works. any arrangement is fine provided the arrangement is consistent across all images.

Comment: Just as a foot note, if your image size is big, try reducing the image-dimension using PCA and then cluster. Because kmeans is computationally intensive.